# `\moveleft` and `\centerline` in resume

Tags: horizontal-alignment, resume, cv

I'm adjusting a resume template which is based on `res.cls`.

Here's the part that confuse me:

```
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf John Smith} % Your name at the top    

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{(000) 111-1111 or (111) 111-1112}
```

[image]

I would like to move the name and mobile to the left

```
{\large\bf John Smith} % Your name at the top

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{(000) 111-1111 or (111) 111-1112}
```

[image]

Now it align with the content of resume. How do I force it to align to the left of the resume?

I tried and I could make it by guessing and adjusting a proper value on `\hoffset` but I thinks is not a clean way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper width you want to move the content to the left with is `\sectionwidth`:

```
\hspace*{-\sectionwidth}{\large\bfseries John Smith} % Your name at the top    

\hspace*{-\sectionwidth}(000) 111-1111 or (111) 111-1112
```